# JSF update primefaces tree children

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i want to update the children of the primefaces tree without pulling the whole tree from the server.

I can update the whole tree but not **only** the children of a specific node ...

Edit:

This is an example of my code:

```
<p:tree value="#{cc.tree}" var="wrapper" id="tree" widgetVar="tree" styleClass="commentTree-#{cc.id}">
   <p:treeNode id="treeNode" styleClass="treenode-#{wrapper.id}">
      Hallo: #{wrapper.text}
   </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

Now i want to update a specific treenode.

```
function findIDbySelector(selector) {
    return $(selector).first().attr('id');
}

function updateComponent(clientID) {
    var ajax_json = {};
    ajax_json['source'] = '#{cc.id}';
    ajax_json['update'] = clientID;

    PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest(ajax_json);
}

[...]

updateComponent(findIDbySelector('.treenode-1'));
```

As i said i can update the whole tree but i only want to update a single Treenode.

(The code may contain bugs/typos since it is stripped down)

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to Update the subtrees generated by primefaces but since they are no jsf components this fails. I took a look then how primefaces loads the data in their "dynamic tree" example but they load the whole tree every time a node is expanded, which is no option for me.

Comment: please post your .xhtml and .java files so we can guide you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I crawled a bit through the primefaces sources and saw that they support the loading of the children which is enough for me (i can wrap the contant of the node into a panel and update that and the children).

To update the children i modified the primefaces expandnode method:

```
function loadNodes(tree, c) {
    var a = tree;
    if (tree.cfg.dynamic) {
        if (tree.cfg.cache && c.children(".ui-treenode-children").children().length > 0) {
            tree.showNodeChildren(c);
            return
        }
        if (c.data("processing")) {
            PrimeFaces.debug("Node is already being expanded, ignoring expand event.");
            return
        }
        c.data("processing", true);
        var b = {
            source: tree.id,
            process: tree.id,
            update: tree.id,
            formId: tree.cfg.formId
        };
        b.onsuccess = function (j) {
            var g = $(j.documentElement),
                h = g.find("update");
            for (var e = 0; e < h.length; e++) {
                var l = h.eq(e),
                    k = l.attr("id"),
                    f = l.text();
                if (k == a.id) {
                    c.children(".ui-treenode-children").html(f);
                    a.showNodeChildren(c)
                } else {
                    PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.updateElement.call(tree, k, f)
                }
            }
            PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.handleResponse.call(tree, g);
            return true
        };
        b.oncomplete = function () {
            c.removeData("processing")
        };
        b.params = [{
            name: tree.id + "_expandNode",
            value: a.getRowKey(c)
        }];
        if (tree.hasBehavior("expand")) {
            var d = tree.cfg.behaviors.expand;
            d.call(tree, c, b)
        } else {
            PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest(b)
        }
    } else {
        tree.showNodeChildren(c);
        tree.fireExpandEvent(c)
    }
}
```

An example call could be:

```
loadNodes(tree, $('#j_idt62\\:tree\\:0'));
```

Where `tree` is the WidgetVar of the p:tree

Comment: As a side note: don't refer to elements by their generated id (j_idt..).

Comment: It was only for the example :) i get the id via a unique class: `function findIDbySelector(selector) {
    return $(selector).first().attr('id');
   }`