# Ajax update of non-JSF component with PrimeFaces selectors

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to update any html fragment using Primefaces selectors - PFS?
Consider this:

```
<h:outputText id="test" value="#{testBean.date}"/>
<span id="test2"><h:outputText value="#{testBean.date}"/></span>

<p:commandButton value="test" process="@none" update="@(#test)"/>
<p:commandButton value="test2" process="@none" update="@(#test2)"/>
```

Only first button is refreshing.
It's trival example - my real need is to update some parts of datatable, without refreshing whole component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The update target must not only in client side be obtainable in HTML DOM tree by `document.getElementById()`, but also in server side by [`UIViewRoot#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29), so that JSF can regenerate the desired HTML output which ultimately get applied during the ajax update.

If you supply JSF the ID of a plain HTML element, then it won't find anything in the component tree to regenerate the desired new HTML output for. Just replace the plain HTML element by a JSF component.

The PrimeFaces selectors get ultimately converted to HTML element IDs. PrimeFaces will loop over the elements found by the jQuery selector and extract their `id` attributes before passing to JSF. This is thus essentially the same problem as already answered here: [Is it possible to update non-JSF components (plain HTML) with JSF ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009174/jsf-update-with-ajax-non-jsf-things/13011934#13011934).

Comment: Hmm, any other ideas of refreshing single row/cell in priemfaces datatable?

Comment: Just wrap it in a JSF component and reference it instead?

Comment: @BalusC has this been solved already in the Primefaces 6.1 release?