# Rendering a div with ajax

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this div

```
<div id="name">
    ....
</div>
```

I also have a button that does this:

```
<h:commandLink id="bttn" action="#">
    <f:ajax render="name"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

The problem is that when executing, it says that there is no component called "name". Is there a way I can render a div with an ajax **without enclosing it within a jsf component**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way. Ajax rendering works roughly as follows under JSF's hoods:

```
for (String clientIdToRender : clientIdsToRender) {
    UIComponent componentToRender = viewRoot.findComponent(clientIdToRender);
    // ...
}
```

However, as the plain HTML `<div>` is *not* as a fullworthy JSF component available by [`UIViewRoot#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29), JSF can't find anything to generate the updated HTML output for.

You do not necessarily need to wrap it in another JSF component, you can also just use a JSF component which generates already a HTML `<div>` element. That is the `<h:panelGroup>` component whose `layout` attribute is set to `block` (as in, "render a [block level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) element").

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="name">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Is it possible to update non-JSF components (plain HTML) with JSF ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009174/jsf-update-with-ajax-non-jsf-things/)