# AJAX rendering in JSF not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, render

I am having a problem while doing a render with JSF.

This is my ajax call from a `<form>`

```
<h:commandLink id="link" >
  <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.getSomething()}" render=":form1:elementId" />
</h:commandLink>
```

I have another form `<form1>` which contains a `<Div>` with `id="elementId"` and want to render after the ajax call.

```
<div id="elementId">
  <a id="link" href = "" class="link" data-contentsel="#moreInfo" 
     data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="custom_popover"
     data-id="dataId" aria-describedby="">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

Without the ajax call, if I m clicking on the link I am getting the data wchich is there in `#moreInfo`. But once the rendering is done after ajax call nothing is happening on click of the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering a div with ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769118/rendering-a-div-with-ajax)

Comment: For some elements you could use 'html 5 passTrough' functionality (nor for a div as far as I know, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600823/pure-html-5-tag-support-in-jsf-2 and the references in it