# Update Nested Panel from Backing Bean

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, xhtml, managed-bean

I have a panel with sections.  Each section is separated by a div and has elements in it.
I’m trying to update some of the sections from the backing bean based on a poller.
The poller calls a bean.
  If there is anything to do, the bean should update a table in the first section.
In addition, when a row in the table is selected, the bean should update other sections of the panel.

None of the solutions that I have seen show how to update the nested elements.

The problem is that while I can update the whole panel

```
    PrimeFaces instance = PrimeFaces.current();
    instance.ajax().update("threatForm:threatListPanel");
```

if I try to update anything in the panel

    `PrimeFaces instance = PrimeFaces.current();
    instance.ajax().update("threatForm:threatListPanel:threatListPanelDiv");`

it throws a : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: threatListPanel:

This is the xhtml

```
<h:form id="threatForm">

    <!-- Update the threat list at regular intervals -->
    <p:poll interval="#{threatMonitorView.pollInterval}"  listener="#{threatMonitorView.updateThreatList()}" />

    <p:panel id="threatListPanel" header="Threat Monitor Page">
        <div id="threatListPanelDiv" class="threatPanel">
            <!-- column with threats listed -->
            <div class="threatTableColumn1">
                <p:column>
                    <p:dataTable id="threatListTable" var="singleThreat"
                        widgetVar="threatTable" value="#{threatMonitorView.threats}"
                        selectionMode="single"
                        selection="#{threatMonitorView.selectedThreat}"
                        rowKey="#{singleThreat.uniqueId}" scrollable="false"
                        sortBy="#{singleThreat.timeReceived}">

                        <!-- update the information area when a threat is selected -->
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                            listener="#{threatMonitorView.onRowSelectThreat}" />

                        <p:column headerText="Active Threats">
                            <!-- header stuff -->

                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:column>
                <!-- end of column 1 -->
            </div>
            <!-- End of threatTableColumn1 divider -->

            <!-- Threat info -->
            <div class="threatTableColumn2">
                <p:column id="threatTableColumn2Id">

                    Stuff in this colunm


                </p:column>
                <!-- column 2 end -->
            </div>
            <!-- End of threatTableColumn2 divider -->

            <div id="threatTableColumn3Div" class="threatTableColumn3">
                <p:column>

                    Stuff in this column

                </p:column>

            </div>
            <!-- End of threatTableColumn3 -->

            <div class="threatTableFooter">
                <p:commandButton value="Close" id="threatCloseButton"
                    action="#{threatMonitorView.closeThreatButton()}"
                </p:commandButton>
            </div>
            <!-- End of threatTableFooter divider -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of threatPanel -->
    </p:panel>

</h:form>
```

This is the update bean

```
public void updateThreatList() {

    if (tlm.isThreatListChanged()){
        PrimeFaces instance = PrimeFaces.current();
        instance.ajax().update("threatForm:threatListPanel:threatListPanelDiv");
        tlm.setThreatListChanged(false);
    }
}
```

Is it because I'm updating a div?  I tried other elements

    `PrimeFaces instance = PrimeFaces.current();
    instance.ajax().update("threatForm:threatListPanel:threatListTable");`

 but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.
TIA!

I changed the DIV to this:

```
<div jsf:id="threatListPanelDiv" class="threatPanel">
```

It can't find the component

This is the error:
13:07:45,431 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-1) /WEB-INF/lib/incentcontrol-module-firstview-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/resources/secured-pages/firstview/threatmonitor/threatMonitorView.xhtml @23,57 listener="#{threatMonitorView.updateThreatList()}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: threatListPanel: javax.el.ELException: /WEB-INF/lib/incentcontrol-module-firstview-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/META-INF/resources/secured-pages/firstview/threatmonitor/threatMonitorView.xhtml @23,57 listener="#{threatMonitorView.updateThreatList()}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: threatListPanel
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar:2.2.12-jbossorg-2]
    at org.primefaces.component.poll.Poll.broadcast(Poll.java:251) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar:2.2.12-jbossorg-2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar:2.2.12-jbossorg-2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar:2.2.12-jbossorg-2]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:151) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at de.heimannsystems.jee.incentcontrol.servletfilter.LoginFilter.callNextFilter(LoginFilter.java:97) [incentcontrol-common-3.2.0.jar:]
    at de.heimannsystems.jee.incentcontrol.servletfilter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:55) [incentcontrol-common-3.2.0.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: threatListPanel
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:651) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentTraversalUtils.firstById(ComponentTraversalUtils.java:140) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentById(SearchExpressionFacade.java:526) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveClientId(SearchExpressionFacade.java:338) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveClientId(SearchExpressionFacade.java:292) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.PrimeFaces$Ajax.validateClientId(PrimeFaces.java:290) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.PrimeFaces$Ajax.update(PrimeFaces.java:280) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at de.heimannsystems.jee.incentcontrol.modules.firstview.threatmonitor.ThreatMonitorView.updateThreatList(ThreatMonitorView.java:145) [incentcontrol-module-firstview-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:286) [javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b05-jbossorg-1.jar:3.0.1-b05-jbossorg-1]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b05-jbossorg-1.jar:3.0.1-b05-jbossorg-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.16.SP1.jar:2015-09-16 08:49]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.16.SP1.jar:2015-09-16 08:49]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.16.SP1.jar:2015-09-16 08:49]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.16.SP1.jar:2015-09-16 08:49]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar:2.2.12-jbossorg-2]
    ... 45 more

13:07:45,443 SEVERE [org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler] (default task-1) FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/error.xhtml' will be shown.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: threatListPanel
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:651) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentTraversalUtils.firstById(ComponentTraversalUtils.java:140) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentById(SearchExpressionFacade.java:526) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveClientId(SearchExpressionFacade.java:338) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveClientId(SearchExpressionFacade.java:292) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.PrimeFaces$Ajax.validateClientId(PrimeFaces.java:290) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.primefaces.PrimeFaces$Ajax.update(PrimeFaces.java:280) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at de.heimannsystems.jee.incentcontrol.modules.firstview.threatmonitor.ThreatMonitorView.updateThreatList(ThreatMonitorView.java:145) [incentcontrol-module-firstview-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar:1.0.4.Final]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:286) [javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b05-jbossorg-1.jar:3.0.1-b05-jbossorg-1]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b05-jbossorg-1.jar:3.0.1-b05-jbossorg-1]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.16.SP1.jar:2015-09-16 08:49]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.16.SP1.jar:2015-09-16 08:49]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.16.SP1.jar:2015-09-16 08:49]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.16.SP1.jar:2015-09-16 08:49]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar:2.2.12-jbossorg-2]
    at org.primefaces.component.poll.Poll.broadcast(Poll.java:251) [primefaces-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar:2.2.12-jbossorg-2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar:2.2.12-jbossorg-2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.12-jbossorg-2.jar:2.2.12-jbossorg-2]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:151) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at de.heimannsystems.jee.incentcontrol.servletfilter.LoginFilter.callNextFilter(LoginFilter.java:97) [incentcontrol-common-3.2.0.jar:]
    at de.heimannsystems.jee.incentcontrol.servletfilter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:55) [incentcontrol-common-3.2.0.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar:1.2.9.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]

Comment: Hi, first of all it is not a 'nested panel' but a plain html `div`, secondly you don't update in, but from the bean ;-). The answer to your question is the duplicate (and running in development mode would have gotten you an error most likely)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to update non-JSF components (plain HTML) with JSF ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009174/is-it-possible-to-update-non-jsf-components-plain-html-with-jsf-ajax)

Comment: @Kukeltje - you are correct, it is not a nested panel.  The divs and tables are nested in the panel.  Thanks for correcting my "syntax".  Neither of the solutions (jsf:id and using panelgroup instead of div) worked. : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: threatListPanel:   Other ideas?

Comment: I tried this <div jsf:id="threatListPanelDiv" class="threatPanel" > and <h:panelGroup id="threatListPanelDiv" layout="block" styleclass="threatPanel">

Comment: The `jsf:id` or a panelgroup **is** needed and the solution to _**this**_ problem. If you have a new problem, post a new question with full stacktrace etc... And try making a [mcve] (always do, since it helps narrowing down the problem and other trying to reproduce if they want to)

Comment: Oh wait, you also get this exception when you try to update the datatable (threatlistTable)?

Comment: I didn't try that.  I figured if it couldn't updated the threatListPanelDiv it would not be able to update something inside of it.  What would the syntax be to update the table?

Comment: @Kukeltje - it didn't solve *this* problem.  It solved the problem that you think this duplicates.  Any suggestions for solving this one?  I added the error.

Comment: You mentioned in the question you tried  you tried it... `"threatForm:threatListPanel:threatListTable" ????????????

Comment: Oh and please read the stacktrace correctly!!!!! ... What line is that in your code... ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.
It was a combination of two issues.
First [Is it possible to update non-JSF components (plain HTML) with JSF ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009174/is-it-possible-to-update-non-jsf-components-plain-html-with-jsf-ajax)
I added the jsf:id to the Div

Second from [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)

It says to look in the HTML output for actual client ID

Once I had the jsf:id and the actual client ID it all worked

Comment: Combine 2 your answers in 1, or simple delete other than this answer.

Comment: @VasilLukach - It wouldn't let me delete it so there isn't much point in combining them.  Thanks for the advice