# Primefaces components show wrong value on page load

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `<fr:menu>` in the left panel that contains the list of pages that are available to the user. Depending on the selected page `home.xhtml` updates itself rendering the correct components.
My menu model in `.xhtml`

```
    <fr:menu id="freyaMenu" widgetVar="FreyaMenuWidget" model="#{bean.leftModel}" />
```

the model in `bean.java` is defined:

```
    private MenuModel leftModel;
```

and each element of the model is created basically like this:

```
    DefaultMenuItem.builder().command("#{home.initPage}").build();
```

the page in `home.xhtml` is populated like this:

```
    <h:form id="form">
      ...
        <c:forEach var="el" items="#{home.pageElements}">
          <h:panelGroup rendered="#{el.name == 'inputText'}">
            ...
          </h:panelGroup>
          ...
        </c:forEach>
      ...
    </h:form>
```

in `home.java`:

```
    private List<Map> pageElements;
```

The problem is that in some cases when the page loads I have components that show different content from what I actually have in the `bean`. For example there are `<p:inputText>` components that show the value contained in the `<p:inputText>` that was in the same i-th position within the previous page, another case is that some `<p:pickList>` components do not show the rows assigned to them until an `event` is executed via another component present in the page or it also happens that some `<p:autocomplete>` components show an `empty` or `null` value when a value is correctly assigned to them in the `bean`.

What could cause such a display error?

This problem showed up when I ran the following method which redirected the page:

```
    public String initPage(MenuActionEvent menuActionEvent) {
      // init of the selected page
      ...
      return "home";
    }
```

I temporarily solved this series of problems by changing the `initPage` method:

```
    public void initPage(MenuActionEvent menuActionEvent) {
      // init of the selected page
      ...
      PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("window.location.href = \"home.xhtml\";");
    }
```

but this version of `initPage` causes a graphical effect corresponding to a double loading of the page (client side only).

What could be causing this and how can I resolve it?

Thanks.

I tried to follow Nikola's advice by replacing the `<c:foreach>` with a `<ui:repeat>`

> ok i see now, it is a bean. c:forEach executes at START of jsf
> lifecycle. In most cases JSF lifecycle does NOT have correct values in
> beans at that point. for example, i use c:: tags only for user roles,
> bbecause they are "static" even before first response. BalusC has
> realy good articles about c: tags and JSF lifecycle and why it is NOT
> recommended in most of the cases

however I have components inside the `<ui:repeat>` that must take on a dynamic `id` so as to be able to perform updates on individual components given that in certain situations it is wrong to update the entire page. Also following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13011934/11377966 and updating the jsf-api version to 2.2.20, my current state turns out to be:

```
    <h:form id="form">
      ...
        <ui:repeat var="el" value="#{home.pageElements}">
          ...
          <div jsf:id="element-#{el.customId}">
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{el.name == 'inputText'}">
              ...
            </h:panelGroup>
          </div>
          ...
        </ui:repeat>
      ...
    </h:form>
```

and now the id produced by jsf always ends with "element-" ignoring the value of `#{el.customId}`

Comment: what is "home" bean? most likely you shouldn't use c:forEach, but ui:repeat instead. it has to do with JSF lifecycle.

Comment: ok i see now, it is a bean. c:forEach executes at START of jsf lifecycle. In most cases JSF lifecycle does NOT have correct values in beans at that point. for example, i use c:: tags only for user roles, bbecause they are "static" even before first response. BalusC has realy good articles about c: tags and JSF lifecycle and why it is NOT recommended in most of the cases

Comment: Thanks @Nikola for the reply, I tried to follow your advice and updated the question with my new situation